# How to make mirror works?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror

[image]

Guys could you help me figure this out?

Left: the one i made

Right: the one i want it to turn out

Comment: Pay attention on the origin location; it's likely positioned somewhere in the middle of the mesh on the left.

Answer (score 0):

In the mirror modifier you most likely have it set to mirror on the wrong axis. It could be set to X when it needs to be set to Y or maybe to Z. Just experiment with the different axis settings to see which one works. Also, If you want it to join at the center of the two sides which is great for modeling, use the clipping setting. Hope this helped! ;)